# Why can't IntelliJ IDEA resolve destroyMethod="close"?

Tags: intellij-idea, annotations, javabeans

I'm looking to add `destroy-method = "close"` to a bean, but IDEA 14 doesn't seem to like it.  Anyone know why?

[image]

[image]

Also tried `"shutdown"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because class `DataSource` does not have a method `close`.

Comment: Then how would we emulate this?  `<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>` from https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Spring-Hibernate

Comment: Change return type to some class which has `close` method, in your case it would be  `public HikariDataSource dataSource(){...}`.

Comment: Oops - didn't see that

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing the following line of code.

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it